Complicated declarations in C
I am trying to understand complicated declarations in C, and I wrote a sample function that takes as argument an array of integers of length 10 and returns a pointer to an array of length 10 of integers -
int (*x(int arr[10]))[10] {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arr[i] = 1;
    }

    return &arr[10];
}


int main() {

    int array[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    x(array);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }
}

But I do not understand what to put as return. &arr[10] gives an error cannot convert 'int*' to 'int (*)[10]' in return. &arr also gives the same error. So what should be the appropriate return statement?

Why would you want to return a pointer to a local variable in the first place?

I'm not sure what you are trynig to achieve. But if you need x to accept and array and set all it's elements to 1, you can simply declare it as void x(int arr[10]). When you'll pass array from main it will decay into a pointer, and you don't seem to use (or need) any return value from x anyway.

I am not trying to achieve anything, really. I just wrote a sample function to understand complicated declarations.

return &arr[10]; returns a poiter to the "end" of array (i.e. the next element past the end - index 10).

@Lundin It's not a local variable, it is an array parameter passed by address. Nothing local about it.

@user207421 Yeah that's true though the code as is attempts to return an address to the pointer. The pointer is a local variable. Anyway, I posted an answer.

The problem is an half-century-old conundrum of C, and is inherited by C++ for compatibility. Whenever you use a name of array in an expression it degrades to a pointer to its first element. Argument of return in an expression. You have to upgrade it back:
return (int(*)[10])(arr);

Don't do that in C++! Use an aggregate, e.g. std::array.
Syntax T arg[N] for formal fuction argument in C used to be  an extension and became standard in 90s. It is actually same as T* but offers a possibility of type-compatibility check, albeit it's just a warning for gcc. For similar reasons it's not allowed to return an array by a value or assign an array to an array - it turns out to be attempt to assign to an rvalue pointer.
A Ian an Lundin hadmetioned, we coud use aray sizefor strict type checking if we pass apointer o multidimensional array. Before stnadard common way T (*arr)[10], which was a pointer to exactly 10 elements or T arr[][10] an array of some size,where each element is an array of 10.
T arr[expr][N][M]... is allowed in standard now as long as expr is a legal expression and following sizes N, M,... are constant integers. Compiler still assumes it being T arr[][N][M]..., expr is a hint for self-documentation and static analyzer.
It's wasn't a canon approach to return a pointer to array. It's possible in modern standards but as you see it allows only partial type safety.
You can't even use age-old sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int) C++ anti-pattern, because in C sizeof(arr) is a size of a pointer. Which works differently in C++.
A canonical look for such function would be something like memXXX functions:
#include <stddef.h>

int *x(int arr[], size_t sz){   // or int* arr , doesn't matter  
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        arr[i] = 1;
    }   
    return arr;
}

Static-analyzer-friendly would be:
int *x(size_t sz, int arr[sz]){   
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        arr[i] = 1;
    }   
    return arr;
}

// you'll get a warning if your array it too small
int arr [9];
x(10,arr);

compare to the somewhat correct approach in C++, we must use references or be endangered by type-punning threat, there is no longer a way to push an array of incorrect size:
template <class T, size_t N>
T (&x(T (&arr)[N]))[N] {    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        arr[i] = 1;
    }   
    return arr;
}

Again, better not to do it that way but use std::array.

Arguably, the canonical look in C would rather be void x (size_t sx, int arr[size])

@Lundin if we look at library functions (ISO or POSIX), they don't use that. Plus that's kind of weird both to restrict size of array to some constant "size" and pass the size. Returning pointer to processed array is also kind of library canon.

@Lundin I vaguelly remember that some C compiler of  Quick C era was allowing void x (size_t size, int arr[size]) but that's kind of syntax sugar which got a limited use of readability, it still was int *arr. Are you suggesting they moved it to standard? I'm somewhat out of touch with C

You described T arg[N] in formal argument syntax as an extension, but didn't K&R1 support that syntax in the parameter declaration list?

@Swift-FridayPie That's fully standard compliant since 25 years back.

@Lundin Ah.. well, what's within[] is actually fully ignored by compiler when binding arguments when void x (size_t size, int arr[size]); int arr [10]; x(5,arr);, so nothing is new there. void x (size_t sx, int arr[size]) assumes size to be declared at least and being 0, it's same as int arr[].

@IanAbbott I carefully wrote "Originally", I'll update

@Swift-FridayPie For one-dimensional arrays, it is just self-documenting code. But for arrays of arrays, it adds additional type safety while allowing a multi-dimensional array of any size to use the function.

Yeah, because it' no longer type of array in that case, it's type of element of array.  That means that T is different, e.g. T is int[10] in int arr[][10]. That's pre-stadard  though. We could write int (*arr)[10]

The problem is that when you pass an array as a function parameter, it gets adjusted to a pointer to the first element. int arr[10] as a function parameter is 100% equivalent to int* arr. That's basics you need to be familiar long before playing with this mildly useful pointer-to-array syntax.
Additionally &arr[10] is obviously just nonsense since 10 is array indexing and this returns the address of an array item 1 item out-of-bounds of the array.
Therefore to fix this, you need to do:
int (*x(int (*arr)[10]))[10]  {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        (*arr)[i] = 1;
    }
    return arr;
}

Where x is a function

int(*x(...))[10] returning an int (*)[10],
with a parameter int (*arr)[10] - pointers to array do not get adjusted.

Note that the body of the function has to be changed accordingly and on the caller side you must do x(&array);.

Alternatively, the original code could have used a cast like:
return (int(*)[10])arr;

But that's an unsafe cast and we should only do things like that if we know for sure that what arr points at is indeed an int [10]. The function in itself can't know that because there's no type safety here and the caller might pass an array with other bounds.

Notably, none of this messed up syntax is particularly useful for real-world applications.

I know the relationship between pointers and arrays. I tried 'return arr', 'return &arr', but they still give the same error, so I tried 'return &arr[10]', that doesn't work either.

@ArnavNadkarni If you know, then you don't type random stuff and try to get code working with trial & error :) There is no way you can obtain an int (*)[10] from an int*, the type information has been lost along the way. If you know for sure that it points to an int [10] then another option would have been to cast. Your original code with return (int(*)[10])arr; would have worked, but thats an unsafe cast.

One reason pointers to arrays are not very useful is that such code (like the function here) can only handle arrays of that specific length. That's the underlying motivation for the adjustment of array arguments to simple element pointers in the common core C and C++: That way, arrays of any length can be handled by the same function. Addresses (or references) of arrays of specific length become more useful in C++ where the array length can be a template parameter.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Yep, the correct solution to whatever this was supposed to solve is very likely to pass along the size as a parameter or to wrap size + array inside a struct.
